# XAML: Confusing about binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i created 2 simple class like so:

```
public class Car
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string CheckInDateTime { get; set; }
}
public class CarDataSource
{
    private static ObservableCollection<Car> _myCars=new ObservableCollection<Car>();
    public  static ObservableCollection<Car> GetCars()
    {
        if(_myCars.Count==0)
        {
            _myCars.Add(new Car() { ID = 1, Name = "A", Model = "Yamaha", });
            _myCars.Add(new Car() { ID = 2, Name = "B", Model = "Toyota" });
            _myCars.Add(new Car() { ID = 3, Name = "C", Model = "Suzuki" });
        }
        return _myCars;
    }
}
```

In the MainPage.xaml.cs, I called the static  GetCars() method to wire up the CarViewModel for the MainPage.xaml:

```
public ObservableCollection<Car> CarViewModel = CarDataSource.GetCars();
```

and finally is binding to the view model in xaml file:

```
<Page
x:Class="BindingCommand.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:BindingCommand"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
DataContext="{Binding CarViewModel,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView x:Name="myListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="dataTemplate">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,20,0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Make}" FontSize="24"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model}" FontSize="24"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Button Content="Check In"
                                Width="100"
                                Height="50"
                                Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CheckInDateTime}" FontSize="24"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

but when i compliled and ran it, it showed me nothing. 
but then i fixed CarViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Car> _CarViewModel = CarDataSource.GetCars();
    public ObservableCollection<Car> CarViewModel
    {
        get { return this._CarViewModel;} 
    }
```

and it resulted as i want. 
I still don't know how it worked :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bindings in WPF/Xaml are always resolved against properties. In the first case, you had a public field, so the binding system didn't find a match for the path "CarViewModel". If you watched your output window when running in the debugger, there was probably a binding error there.

When you changed it to a property, the binding process was able to find it and it worked.

Comment: thanks a lot for your point of view. Now i think i should learn about the differences between field and property :)